# How to make all sheets in workbook visible using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel workbook has 4 sheets but the VBA editor shows 5 sheets in same workbook.

[image]

How do I make all sheets visible?

Comment: Select the sheet in the VBA IDE project tree. Change the `Visible` property below.

Comment: I tried, but error message : Unable to set the Visible property of the Worksheet class

Comment: Problem solved... thanks G Serg

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include a title more appropriate to the actual problem. As it sits, this question is useless for any future visitor to try and solve their own (possibly identical) problem.

Comment: As @Jepped said, your title will have no meaning to future readers who are trying to solve a similar (or identical) problem. Your title should describe the actual problem you're having or question you're asking; *please look at these screenshots* does neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited Answer. See comments from Jeeped and Gserg**(at original question)

Maybe the missing worksheet is very hidden.

Try this code to unhide it.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
    ws.Visible = True
Next
End Sub
```

Changing the visible property in the properties-window also works.

Comment: I might have simply made all worksheets visible rather than bothering to determine the current status of each beforehand.

Comment: is it possible to replace "sheets" word in "For Loop" statement? Otherwise "Sheets" word is mandatory here

Comment: @saikrishna - In this loop, **Sheets** represents the workbook's [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508.aspx); i.e. all of the worksheets in the workbook whether they are visible or not. So... no, you cannot replace **Sheets** unless you are replacing it with **Worksheets** (which would skip Chart sheets and Macro sheets).

Comment: @Jeeped - Ok, Thank you, Now. I got the uses of "Worsheets" and "sheets".